# Julia mapslices function equivalent in Python

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, julia

I'm trying to find if there's a convenient equivalent to mapslices function from the Julia language to Python. Here's the line I'm trying to convert:

```
line_center = float64(mapslices(x->sum(x.^4.*[1:length(x)])./sum(x.^4),no_background,1)[:])
```

Comment: I'm thinking it might be: numpy.apply_along_axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone wondering, here's an answer.

```
def exp_func(x):
    return np.dot(np.arange(len(x)), np.power(x, 4))/(np.sum(np.power(x, 4)))

result = np.apply_along_axis(exp_func,axis = 0,array)
```

exp_func takes 1-D arrays.